# SFINAE-friendly test for object deletability

Tags: c++, gcc, template-meta-programming, sfinae, delete-operator

I'm interested in programmatically determining whether a *delete-expression* is valid for some given object.  It seems like one should be able to do this using SFINAE.  The code I have come up with works like I expect with Clang 6.0.1, but fails to compile with GCC 7.3.0.

Two questions: 1) is there a better way to achieve the goal, and 2) who's right?

```
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

// C++14 variant of void_t
template< typename ...T > struct void_type { typedef void type; };
template< typename ...T > using void_t = typename void_type<T...>::type;

template< typename T, typename = void_t<> > struct Deletable : false_type { };
template< typename T >
struct Deletable<T, void_t<decltype(delete declval<T>())> > : true_type { };
//        Here's the SFINAE'd test  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

struct A {
    operator signed *() const;
};

struct B {
    operator signed *() const;
    operator unsigned *() const;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(Deletable<A>::value, "Couldn't delete A objects but "
        "should be able to.");
    static_assert(!Deletable<B>::value, "C objects are deletable but "
        "shouldn't be because pointer-to-object is ambiguous.");
    return 0;
}
```

---

### My attempt at answering q.2

tl;dr: I think Clang is right.  Skip to the bottom for a few other test cases.

Here's why, using [N4140](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf).

The relevant section about the *delete-expression* when given a class type reads [expr.delete] p.1:

> [...] If of class type, **the operand [of the *delete-expression*] is *contextually implicitly converted* to a pointer to object type**.  The *delete-expression*’s
>   result has type `void`.

Note that `void *` is not a "pointer to object".  Here we find that the result of the `decltype(delete <blah>)` is `void`: it is not a dependent expression.  However, I think for SFINAE we're just interested in whether or not it's well-formed.

The conversion is done according to [conv] p.5:

> An expression e of class type E appearing [as a *delete-expression*'s operand] is
>   said to be *contextually implicitly converted* to a specified type T and
>   is well-formed if and only if e can be implicitly converted to a type
>   T that is determined as follows: **E is searched for conversion
>   functions whose return type is cv T or reference to cv T such that T
>   is allowed by the context. There shall be exactly one such T.**

Since `T` needs to be a pointer-to-object, we see that class `A` meets the conversion criteria (and is therefore deletable) by providing a single conversion-to-object-pointer function whereas `B`, providing two such functions, does not.  Thus, trying to delete a B object should result in an ill-formed expression.  This is what the `static_assert`s in the above code are supposed to ensure.

Possible alternative approach: can one test an object for "convertability to *some* pointer to object type"?

Carrying on, here's the definition of an invalid expression for the purpose of type substitution [type.deduct] p.8:

> If a substitution results in an invalid type or expression, type
>   deduction fails. **An invalid type or expression is one that would be
>   ill-formed, with a diagnostic required, if written using the
>   substituted arguments.** [...] Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type and its template parameter types can result in a deduction failure.  [ Note: The evaluation of the substituted types and expressions can result in side effects such as the instantiation of class template specializations and/or function template specializations, the generation of implicitly-defined functions, etc. Such side effects are not in the “immediate context” and can result in the program being ill-formed. — end note ]

As far as I can tell, since deleting a `B` object is ill-formed (with diagnostic required), the `decltype(delete <b>)` expression should be invalid making SFINAE kick in.  Deletable then ends up inheriting from false_type, and we're golden.

With Clang, that seems to be the case.  With GCC, here's the result:

```
main.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class T> struct Deletable<T, typename
    void_type<T, decltype (delete (declval<T>)())>::type> [with T = B]’:
main.cpp:24:32:   required from here
main.cpp:24:32: error: ambiguous default type conversion from ‘B’
    static_assert(!Deletable<B>::value, "Shouldn't be able to delete B objects "
                               ^~
main.cpp:24:32: note:   candidate conversions include ‘B::operator int*()
    const’ and ‘B::operator unsigned int*() const’
main.cpp:24:32: error: type ‘struct B’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected
    pointer
```

My guess is that GCC does not consider the contextual implicit conversion as part of the immediate context, so the ambiguity becomes a hard error rather than just a type deduction failure.  Given the apparent intent of the "immediate context" as defined in the note above, I think the conversion *should* be in the immediate context.  Therefore, as above, I think Clang is right.

For completeness, other possible reasons an object may not be deletable are:

```
class C {
    ~C();
public:
    operator C*() const;
};

struct D {
    ~D() = delete;
    operator D*() const;
};

struct E {
    operator E*() const;
private:
    void operator delete(void*);
};

int main() {
    static_assert(!Deletable<C>::value, "C objects are deletable but shouldn't "
        "be because destructor is private.");
    static_assert(!Deletable<D>::value, "D objects are deletable but shouldn't "
        "be because destructor is deleted.");
    static_assert(!Deletable<E>::value, "E objects are deletable but shouldn't "
        "be because deallocation function is inaccessible.");
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine in Clang, and, interestingly, the `static_assert()` for `D` passes for GCC, however the `C` and `E` cases fail.

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct Deletable<C>’:
main.cpp:31:32:   required from here
main.cpp:11:76: error: ‘C::~C()’ is private within this context
 struct Deletable<T, void_t<T, decltype(delete declval<T>())> > : true_type { };
                                                                            ^
main.cpp:14:5: note: declared private here
     ~C();
     ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:31:5: error: static assertion failed: C objects are deletable but shouldn't be because destructor is private.
     static_assert(!Deletable<C>::value, "C objects are deletable but shouldn't "
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:31:20: error: ‘C::~C()’ is private within this context
     static_assert(!Deletable<C>::value, "C objects are deletable but shouldn't "
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:14:5: note: declared private here
     ~C();
     ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct Deletable<E>’:
main.cpp:35:32:   required from here
main.cpp:11:76: error: ‘static void E::operator delete(void*)’ is private within this context
 struct Deletable<T, void_t<T, decltype(delete declval<T>())> > : true_type { };
                                                                            ^
main.cpp:27:10: note: declared private here
     void operator delete(void*);
          ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:35:5: error: static assertion failed: E objects are deletable but shouldn't be because deallocation function is inaccessible.
     static_assert(!Deletable<E>::value, "E objects are deletable but shouldn't "
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:35:20: error: ‘static void E::operator delete(void*)’ is private within this context
     static_assert(!Deletable<E>::value, "E objects are deletable but shouldn't "
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:27:10: note: declared private here
     void operator delete(void*);
          ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Why do you use this `void_t` definition? It is non-deduced context and thats the reason why GCC is complaining.

Comment: The reason is that C++14 doesn't specify whether unused template arguments in an alias template are ignored or not.  [CWG1558](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558) says they must not be ignored, but defining it like I have sidesteps the problem.  Which part do you mean is non-deduced?

Comment: You should write @OZ17 , if you want to notify this commenter.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler thanks for the tip.